# Table Rates with Free Shipping

Tags: shipping, table-rates

I have a `tablerates.csv` containing my postcodes range along with weight and price.

For ex: 
`weight = 1 then price = 10
weight = 2 then price = 15`

The above is working for me, but I have a requirement where I need to set Free Shipping for products with weight 0.

`weight = 0 then price = 0`

I have added the code in csv for the same, but its not reflecting somehow.

Pls help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Magento doesn't provide natively this option. To achieve this, you can define a new product attribute and add it for those products whose weight is 0. Then go to "Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules" and you can define a new rule of free shipping for matching items only (i.e. those with the new attribute). In the following link this idea is explained step by step:

http://www.immense.net/magento-free-shipping-certain-products/